# Typing in the search box, system got stuck, unable to perform continuous typing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

While typing in the search box of a react hooks web page, typing got stuck in between and display the blog content, unable to perform continuous typing. Could someone please advise what is it happening here ? I have added my `codesandbox` link for reference !

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-feynman-f30dup?file=/src/App.js

```
const blogData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    date: "25 Jan 2023",
    photo: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
    heading: "DevOps",
    blogDetails:
      "Best heading added here. The most relevant data added here. Greatest of all time. Wont be a good idea play here always."
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    date: "22 Jan 2022",
    photo: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
    heading: "Simple blog",
    blogDetails:
      "Best heading added here. The most relevant data added here. Greatest of all time. Wont be a good idea play here always."
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    date: "22 Jan 2021",
    photo: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
    heading: "Cypress blog",
    blogDetails:
      "Best heading added here. The most relevant data added here. Greatest of all time. Wont be a good idea play here always."
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    date: "21 Jan 2022",
    photo: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
    heading: "React blogs",
    blogDetails:
      "Best heading added here. The most relevant data added here. Greatest of all time. Wont be a good idea play here always."
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    date: "21 Jan 2022",
    photo: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
    heading: "Javascript",
    blogDetails:
      "Best heading added here. The most relevant data added here. Greatest of all time. Wont be a good idea play here always."
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    date: "22 Jan 2022",
    photo: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
    heading: "Unix",
    blogDetails:
      "Best heading added here. The most relevant data added here. Greatest of all time. Wont be a good idea play here always."
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [blogList, setBlogList] = useState(blogData);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchResults(blogData);
  }, []);

  const results = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      searchResults.filter((blog) => {
        return (
          blog.heading.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
          blog.heading.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm)
        );
      }),
    [searchTerm, searchResults]
  );

  const Columns = () => (
    <div className="blogItems">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="blogArea">
          {results.map(({ id, date, photo, heading, blogDetails }) => (
            <a href="https://google.com">
              <div className="blogImageSection">
                <img alt="name" src={photo} />
                <div key={id} className="dataArea">
                  <span className="dataDate">{date}</span>
                  <span className="tags">cypress</span>
                  <h3>{heading}</h3>
                  <p>
                    The most relevant data added here. It will be a good idea.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>Column 2</div>
    </div>
  );

  const SearchArea = () => (
    <div className="searchArea">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="searchbox">
          <div className="sboxcolumnn-2">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="searchbox"
              placeholder="search blogs.."
              value={searchTerm}
              onChange={handleChange}
            ></input>
            <div className="sboxcolumnn-1">
              <img src="images/search.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div id="App">
      <div className="logoheader">
        <h1>Blogs</h1>
      </div>
      <SearchArea />
      <div className="container"></div>
      <h2>Collection Of Blogs</h2>
      <Columns />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: For some reason, everytime you type, the input lost it's focus, and you can't continue to type

Comment: You should either move `SearchArea` declaration outside of the component you have and make it a normal standalone component, either to wrap it with useCallback with props like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-cherry-z6femx?file=/src/App.js) (with empty deps array). Also, dont forget to add `keys` inside your `.map`.

Comment: Thanks Sergey Sosunov, Could you please explain a bit what is happening in that callback () please ?

Comment: Honestly - question "why" is a bit more complicated than original question, answer is in the internals of React and in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html). What useCallback changes for you - every time the parent component is rerendered - child component as a function (reference) is preserved, it does not unmount-create-mount (losing focus), it just rerenders, `componentWillUnmount` vs `componentWillUpdate` (as per my understanding).